# how to select files in a directory with the boolean operator AND

Tags: grep, find, regular-expression

I want to select (find/grep/ls) certain files in a directory starting with certain words and ending with a certain extension. Example:

- bluebelt_hans_hoff.jpg
- bluebelt_hans_hoff.JPEG
- bluebelt_peter_gort.jpg
- bluebelt_peter_gort.JPEG

I only want the files starting with "bluebelt" AND ending with only the ".jpg" extension (and not the JPEG extension). How to do this on the commandline?

Answer (score 3):

If you just want to list the files in the terminal, use:

```
ls -d bluebelt*.jpg
```

If you want to do something with those files, use:

```
for file in bluebelt*.jpg; do
    your_command "$file"
done
```

Answer (score 1):

```
find /dir/with/yor/files -type f -iname 'bluebelt*.jpg'
```

Advantage of this method over the `ls`-driven is in that than this method will find a files only while behaviour of the `ls` may be unexpected. Let's say if you have a dir named as bluebelt1.jpg then the `ls` utility will output all the files contained in this dir.

Thought this variant has two things. (1) it will search case-insensitively. If you does not want specify `-name`. (2) it will search recursively. If you does not want you could use the `-maxdepth`. Please see the `man find` for explanation.

Comment: Read up on `ls -d`

Comment: @roaima, yes, but it still output a dirs etc...